# Select all checkbox with icheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox, icheck

I am using [iCheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/) plugin for checkbox. I put a "Select all" functionality at there. The structure:

- Select all
- Checkbox 1
- Checkbox 2
- Checkbox 3

It works fine like when check on "Select all", all the checkboxes will checked. when uncheck "Select all", all the checkboxes will unchecked. But, after checking "Select all", if making any checkbox unchecked, "Select all" should be unchecked too automatically as at that time all checkbox are not checked.

[image]

To make this, I have written this:

```
$('#check-all').on('ifChanged', function(event){
    if($('.check').filter(':checked').length == $('.check').length) {
        $('#check-all').iCheck('check');
    } else {
        $('#check-all').iCheck('uncheck');
    }
    $('#check-all').iCheck('update');
});
```

But, after putting this code, my checkboxes are not working fine like "Select all" doesn't work with single click, it need multiple click often. Also "Select all" is not unchecking when any single checkbox is unchecked. What's the problem with the code? How to write it correctly?

[Fiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/86x2bc2r/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
// Remove the checked state from "All" if any checkbox is unchecked
$('.check').on('ifUnchecked', function (event) {
    $('#check-all').iCheck('uncheck');
});

// Make "All" checked if all checkboxes are checked
$('.check').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    if ($('.check').filter(':checked').length == $('.check').length) {
        $('#check-all').iCheck('check');
    }
});
```

handling `$('#check-all').on('ifUnchecked', ...` is tricky though - it fires the other handling and every checkbox gets unchecked

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjf5ryhv/)

Comment: I have put your code into my fiddle. It seem, it don't work perfectly still.
http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/86x2bc2r/2/

Comment: @user1896653 and fixed the handlers a bit

Comment: There is a problem. See the screenshot please. I hope, you'll understand it.
http://i.imgur.com/ZlUHcuT.jpg

Comment: @user1896653 thanks for thorough testing. yeah, that code is very leaky. can be fixed https://jsfiddle.net/vjf5ryhv/ but it still stinks. to do it properly instead of shared state one need to pass some information in iCheck call, but i did not find a way to do it

Comment: Thanks for your help. Though, it's not in good practice probably, it seems working perfectly. I will go with this if I don't find any other good.

Comment: Thanks man i was facing same problem and its helped me lot..Up Vote :)

Comment: Thanks Mate, you saved my day